# MySQL and Windows Store C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I've been searching about this on Google and I did find some useful stuff but I'm not totally sure if that's what I need so I'll ask here.

I'm trying to make a Windows Store application and I want to connect to a simple MySQL database that's on the server. What's the easiest or best way to do that? Whenever I need local databases I use Entity Framework. Is it possible to use it here and if so, are there any tutorials that cover everything that I need to install as well as some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you : read more about Database Engine :) cause once you connect you DB Engine to a Database : either it is local or on remote machine (Server) its the same thing when you look at it from your application.

1- First watch this read more about this : [SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx)

2- watch this (how you connect to a remote database) [enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aufh35uE8YU)

3- Very important is to allow connection from Remote Machine [enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIovZluNmNs)

4- Once you are able to connect to the remote database from your SQL Server, everythg is the same on EF.